# Set Defaults on attribute

Tags: enterprise-architect

In EA I when I am adding attributes to a class I use the insert button.  I would like to change the default new attribute to be public and of type string.  I quickly did a search and found nothing.  EA is hard to search for based on so many bogus responses.

So I thought I would quickly ask here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fairly sure there isn't an option for this.

If you create your own UML profile (with a customized diagram type), you can set the default attribute type for attributes created from the diagram toolbox (not from within the Properties dialog), but even then there isn't a way to specify the default visibility.